# How to check netflix zuul is redirecting request to appropriate service

Tags: netflix-zuul

Could you please help me with the code snippet which will help to determine whether netflix zuul is redirecting request to appropriate service.

I am using spring boot & zuul 1.x.

RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest().getRequestURI().toString(); gives me the url which is initiated by browser client, however I am not able to figure out how to make sure zuul is redirecting this request internally to proper service.Which will help in testing without running the actual service.

Thanks,
Shekhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try looking at the source code of pre-decoration filter, basically what it does is determines where and how to route based on the supplied. Also sets various proxy related headers for downstream requests

```
context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();    
request = context.getRequest();
```

call the getRouteHost method on context object it will give you all the route related information like protocol, host, port etc..

```
RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRouteHost();
```

to get the uri call getRequestURI on request object

```
 request.getRequestURI()
```

**NOTE: the problem you might be having was the order of your filter, since preDecorationFilter has order of 5**

```
@Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER;
    }
```

which is actually 5 (as far as i remember), make sure your filter order is greater than 5, i tried with filter order 7 and everything is working as expected, put your intelligence code in the run method()

Comment: thanks for your inputs. However I am not getting expected result after following suggestions. What I am trying to achieve here is e.g. In application.yml file I have entry for zuul as follows
 zuul:
 prefix: /api
routes:
 foo-service:
 path: /foo-service/**
 url: http://localhost:8300
In this case if I heat url "http://localhost:8302/api/foo-service/rest/foo/Peter", how I can make sure zuul is redirecting request internally to "http://localhost:8300/rest/foo/Peter". Please correct me if I am missing somthing here.

Comment: have u tried looking at serviceID in the code mentioned above, i think route.location() should provide what you are looking for

Comment: ProxyRouteLocator has been deprecated, so I have used SimpleRouteLocator and have passed  "ServletPath" (/api/foo-service/rest/foo/Sam) to getMatchingRoute. However it returns me "null" route due to which it fails to give me  "getLocation"(serviceID)

Comment: i m assuming that you are doing this in some filter, if so what is the filter order of that filter? also in your zuul configuration  are you using direct url or service id?

Comment: thanks for reply please have a look at following information  
1) yes, I am doing this in RouteFilter 
2) Filterorder is "0" (zero) 
3) In zuul configuration I am using direct url

Comment: edited my original answer based on input, tried also on my end, have a look pls